# Controlling the Rotation of bike automatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bike stunt game and I want that if user is not rotating the bike it gets back to the zero rotation ignoring all forces. Working with rotations seems very complicated.

```
if (body.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 25)
    body.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, -inAirRotationSpeed * 30 * Time.deltaTime));
else if (body.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 10)
    body.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, inAirRotationSpeed * 30 * Time.deltaTime));
else
    body.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```

I have tried this code but doesn't seem to work properly I think Conditions need to be change
can anyone help me with that.
I can provide the full script if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, rotations are very complicated. You're trying to read out the euler angles of a rotation, which is the simple x-y-z axes of rotation. However, rotation is saved as a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html), which is a fancy math way of having the "true" rotation saved. There's multiple ways you could roll-pitch-yaw to get the same rotation, but there's only ever 1 unique quaternion to represent it.
All that to say, `body.rotation.eulerAngles` can give you a seemingly weird result (explained in [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html)). Which means `if (body.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 25)` is unreliable.

What you could do is use `Quaternion.Angle(body.rotation, Quaternion.identity)` ([docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html)) to get the angle between the current rotation of the bike and the unrotated state ([Quaternion.identity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html)). Then use that angle in your if statements.
Instead of using forces, you could also use `Quaternion.RotateTowards` ([docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)) to not have unexpected speedup/wobbling in some cases. Forces can become finnicky, especially since you're setting the angular velocity directly.

Comment: this solved half of the problem
when it flips to back it gets back to the position I want but when it flips to front it doesn't care.
how should I detect when it flips to front because it doesn't return a negative value. any suggestions

Comment: bro can you help me with that?

Comment: @AbdulRehman The Quaternion.Angle will only return a positive angle. This is why I suggested using `Quaternion.RotateTowards`, since you can put `Quaternion.Identity` in (which is something not rotated at all) and it'll give you a rotation that's towards it. Apply that to the bike and it should start rotating back to it's starting position.

Comment: @AbdulRehman The only thing you might have to avoid then is that, if the bike is perfectly upside down, it might rotate over the wrong axis.

Comment: Sometimes working with Quaternion rotations indeed is quite complex ... instead you could try and use your **up** vector, project it on a Plane that aligns with your **right** vector and then use `Vector3.SignedAngle` in order to compare to the global up vector